# XML text file with `^@` characters in it?

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding, conversion

I have an XML file that I need to parse. When I open it in nano, nano give me the message `(converted from Mac format)`. However between each character, there is a `^@` sequence, like so:

```
^@t^@h^@e^@ ^@q^@u^@i^@c^@k^@ ...
```

What format is this, and how do I get it to display properly? How do I convert it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a double byte format, probably [UTF-16.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2)  See if you can identify a [BOM (Byter Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) header at the beginning of the file.  This will tell you the encoding if it is present, although it may not be.  Note that a text editor may hide this from you, so you will probably need to look at the file with a hex dump utility such as [`od`](http://man.flashnux.com/en/debian/6/6.0.1/man1/hexdump.1.html) or something similar to see the BOM.

A few character set conversion utilities exist that may be of help.  A couple of examples are [`iconv`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.1.html) and [`recode`](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Recode).  You may be able to use one of these to re-code the file into a format that will play nicely with your text editor.

If you need to do the translation programatically, most languages such as Python have libraries for mapping between coding schemes.  [www.unicodetools.com](http://www.unicodetools.com/) shows some of the relevant incantations for various languages.  A good Unicode FAQ can be found [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html) and the Unicode Consortium's [web site](http://www.unicode.org/) has many, many useful resources on the subject.